# Is there any way to Close the JFrame without exiting the whole application using Cancel jButton?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jform

is there any way to close the frame using Cancel button without exiting the whole application.
I tried Following

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
```

above line works only in case when i press X close button to close the frame. Is there any other good way to implement a JButton to perform the same operation

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;


public class CloseTestForm extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    CloseTestForm frame = new CloseTestForm();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public CloseTestForm() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JButton btnSave = new JButton("Save");
        btnSave.setBounds(64, 141, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnSave);

        JButton btnCancel = new JButton("Cancel");
        btnCancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                //??
            }
        });
        btnCancel.setBounds(64, 192, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnCancel);
    }
}
```

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use anything for `setDefaultCloseOperation` excepting `EXIT_ON_CLOSE`.

Then, for the cancel button, just `dispose()` the window. If the application has another running thread, it won't exit. You can also hide a window by calling `setVisible(false)`.

Answer (score 1):

**Call `Window.dispose()` to get rid of a frame.**

You have to add the button and add an actionListener on the button.  Then in the `actionPerformed` method of that action listener, call the `.dispose()` method on the frame you want to get rid of.

Answer (score 1):

- don't extends `JFrame`, create that as local variable
- then you can to call `myFrame.setVisible(false)`
- in this form (code posted here) current JVM never will be expired, untill PC restarted or turned off
- don't create second or more `JFrame`s, use JDialog instead